# Do I need increment pwm_count variable?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

I'm learning VHDL language right now and I have some problems of understanding a part of the code in my course. I don't understand in process freq_counter this statement -> **`if(pwm_count < max_pwm_count)`**, because we don't know the value of max_pwm_count and also **I don't see any incrementation of variable pwm_count**.

Thank you, guys!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use  IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity PWM is
    generic ( 
        freq            : integer := 50; --50Hz
        INPUT_CLK       : integer := 50000000; --50MHz
        BITH_DEPTH      : integer := 8
          );

    Port (    
       ENABLE       : in std_logic;
       CLK          : in std_logic;
       PWM_OUT      : out std_logic;
       DUTY_CYCLE   : in std_logic_vector(BITH_DEPTH-1 downto 0)
          );

end PWM;

architecture behavioral of PWM is

constant max_freq_count    :     integer:= INPUT_CLK/freq;
constant pwm_step          :     integer := max_freq_count/2**BITH_DEPTH;

signal PWM_value        :  std_logic := '0';
signal freq_count       :  integer range from 0 to max_freq_count := 0;
signal pwm_count        :  integer range from 0 to 2**BITH_DEPTH := 0;
signal max_pwm_count    :  integer range from 0 to 2**BITH_DEPTH := 0;
signal pwm_step_count   :  integer range from 0 to max_freq_count := 0;

begin

max_pwm_count <= TO_INTEGER(unsigned(DUTY_CYCLE));
PWM_OUT <= PWM_value;

freq_counter: process(CLK)
begin
if rising_edge(CLK) then 
    if(ENABLE='0') then
       if(freq_count < max_freq_count) then
            freq_count <= freq_count + 1;  
                if(pwm_count < max_pwm_count) then 
                    PWM_value<='1';
                    if(pwm_step_count<pwm_step) then
                        pwm_step_count<=pwm_step_count+1;
                    else
                        pwm_step_count<=0;
                        pwm_count<=0;
                    end if;
                else
                    pwm_value<='0';
                end if;
       else
            freq_count <= 0;
            pwm_count <= 0;
       end if;
    else 
        PWM_value <= '0';
    end if;
end if;
end process freq_counter;

end PWM;
```

Comment: where did you get that code from? It has several issues: integer ranges syntax wrong, inconsistent architecture naming. And - at least to me - it appears even if that would be fixed, it would not do anything meaningful...

Comment: it has to be pulse width modulation but I think it won't be working.

Answer (score 0):

We DO know the value of max_pwm_count : it is initialised to 0 and never re-assigned. Therefore the IF can never be true and ... so on.

As far as incrementing PWM_Count is concerned, your understanding seems to be better than the author's, which puts you in a reasonable position for the necessary re-write.

I recommend first writing a testbench so you can observe its behaviour, and get it correct in simulation.